# how to get stored value from Preferences

Tags: java, preferences

i am trying to store something but i can't figure out how, i have searched and read a lot but i still have one problem.

problem is, if i use: `if(myPreferences.getBoolean(k, true) == true)` when i am trying to get my preferences with key "k" why i have to add there value true/false? how can i get stored value if i wrote into get method new one next to the old key?

i am trying to get the stored value, why add new one? i guess i don't get the concept? idk.

hope it's clear, thanks a lot for answers :-)

Comment: That's just the default value, for if the preference wasn't set it all.

Comment: You don't need the extra `== true` in your if. `if(myPreferences.getBoolean(k, true))` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter on your `getBoolean` call is the default value if `k` doesn't exist yet ([documentation reference).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String,%20boolean))

Presumably, your software requires a preference to be set to some value, and you'll supply a reasonable default.

If you want to test if a preference exists at all, you can use something like [`nodeExists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#nodeExists(java.lang.String)).